# unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> string $itemTypeName]] in class App\Console\Commands\SyncStages

Tags: php, laravel

In order to update multiple entities between local to remote app I've created a console class which is aimed to call every chid classes which sync an entity

so the mother class is :

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Mail\SyncErrorsNotification;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\Models\Stage;
use DateTime;
use DateTimeZone;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Throwable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class SyncIntranetSite extends Command
{

    protected $httpClient;        // GuzzleHttp Client instance 

    //Stages properties
    private $stagesSite;          //list of stages on remote site
    private $stagesIntranet;      //list of stages on intranet
    private $totalUpdatedStages;  //count of updated stages
    private $totalUpToDateStages; //count of up to date stages
    private $updatedStages;       //Array of updated stages 
    private $upToDateStages;      //Array of up to date stages
    private $insertedStages;      //Array of inserted stages
    private $deletedStages;       //Array of deleted stages
    private $syncErrors;

    private $updateTargetStage;   //url of remote stages API controller

    //Sessions properties

    // keywords properties

    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'sync_site:migrate';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Sync CERF internet site with intranet database ';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->httpClient = new Client(['verify'=>false]);

        $this->stagesSite = [];
        $this->stagesIntranet = [];
        $this->totalUpdatedStages = 0;
        $this->totalUpToDateStages = 0;
        $this->updatedStages = [];
        $this->upToDateStages = [];
        $this->insertedStages = [];
        $this->deletedStages = [];
        $this->syncErrors = [];

        $this->updateTargetStage = 'https://preprodcerf2021.cerf.test/stages';
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $this->info('***** Mise à jour automatisée du site internet CERF ******');
        $this->info('retrieving informations...');
        $this->newLine(2);

        //get all stages of current year and next year from intranet
        $this->stagesIntranet = $this->getStagesToCompare();
        //dd(count($this->stagesIntranet));
        //dd($this->stagesIntranet);

        // get all stages of current year and next year from site
        $response = $this->httpClient->get($this->updateTargetStage);
        $this->stagesSite = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
        
        // array of id's in order to know if it must be inserted in site
        $stagesIntranetIds = [];
        foreach ($this->stagesIntranet as $key => $stageIntranet) {
            $stagesIntranetIds[] = $stageIntranet->id_stages;
        }

        $stagesSiteIds = [];
        foreach ($this->stagesSite as $key => $stageSite) {
            $stagesSiteIds[] = $stageSite->id;
        }

        //search all ids not present in stagesSite -> must be inserted
        $arrayDiffIds = array_diff($stagesIntranetIds,$stagesSiteIds);
        $this->newLine(2);
        $this->info('stages not present in site :'.count($arrayDiffIds));
        dump($arrayDiffIds);

        // search all ids present in StageSite -> should maybe be updated after compare their timestamps
        $arrayIntersectIds = array_intersect($stagesIntranetIds,$stagesSiteIds);
        $this->newLine(2);
        $this->info('could be updated :'.count($arrayIntersectIds));
        
        // search all id's present in site not present in intranet query result 
        $arrayDiffIdsToDelete = array_diff($stagesSiteIds,$stagesIntranetIds);
        $this->newLine(2);
        $this->info('must be deleted : '.count($arrayDiffIdsToDelete));


        //Call function to sync all items
        //$this->syncStages($this->stagesIntranet,$stagesSiteIds,$arrayDiffIds,$arrayIntersectIds,$arrayDiffIdsToDelete);

        $syncStages = new SyncStages('stages','http://myendpoint');
...
```

The child class is implements an Interface in order to have standardized methods for all entities

```
class SyncStages extends SyncIntranetSite implements SincItems{

    protected $itemTypeName;
    protected $endpointurl;

    public function __construct(string $itemTypeName, string $endpointUrl ){

        ...
```

but when I call a new SyncStages('myitem','myendpointUrl') in SyncIntranetSite  class i got this weird exception :
BindingResolutionException
unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [  string $itemTypeName]] in class App\Console\Commands\SyncStages

I noticed that when I delete the constructor it works but I want to construct the child passing these 2 parameters, how can I solve this problem ? Thank you.

Comment: Can you share more of your `SyncInternetSite` class? It's possible you've put this somewhere that will end up getting resolved via the DI container

Comment: You can see duplicated vars because I'm going to refactor this not all in mother class but every entities in their classes.

Comment: If I am not confused, your main problem is that constructor's variable `$itemTypeName` is not receiving any data, so it tries to resolve it, and because it cannot be resolved to anything, it gives you that error... You need to share who is calling your command with WHAT data, I am 100% sure you have no data in that variable. And one small tip, if you are using an IDE, please order alphabetically your `use` as it is crazy to read what you are "using" in the big class. If you are not using an IDE, look for a plugin for your software and add something that will follow PSR !